# My Windows 10 Laptop's Wifi Is Turned Off And I Can't Turn It Back ON

Tags: windows-10, wifi-driver, windows-networking

My Windows 10 HP EliteBook 820 laptop has decided that its WiFi adapter is off and I have not figured out how to turn it back on.

In the Networking drop-down, I am told that the WiFi3 is turned off, and I have the choice of a Manual re-enable, or delays of up to 8 hours.

[image: Wi-Fi 3 Turned Off]

If I click the Wi-Fi button at the bottom right, I get a brief listing of the available SSIDs, and then within three seconds the SSIDs go away and I have the above picture again.

I have tried:

- rebooting
- disabling/enabling the WiFi interface
- refreshing the WiFi device driver
- removing both the device and device driver from the Device Manager and forcing a redetection
- going to HP and letting it decide if I needed an updated WiFi driver (it claims that I don't).

The only thing I may have done to provoke this is that I'm not sure if I ever successfully used the WiFi device since the OS upgrade to 1903.

Does anyone have any ideas what I should try next?

Thank you.

Edit: my laptop does have a physical airplane mode button which shows as non-airplane mode. If I press it, the laptop goes into airplane mode (acknowledging as such on the screen), disables Bluetooth, and removes the option to manually enable wifi. Pressing it again puts me back where I am now.

Comment: You should attempt to revert back to the previous version of Windows, in order to eliinate the possability, the problem is due to a compatability issue with 1903.

Comment: Does your computer have a physical airplane mode or wireless radio switch?

Comment: What version is your BIOS currently? I would take five minutes to update it to the current version, just to rule that out completely. It's not necessarily the most likely cause but it's quick and easy, so I would quickly rule it out before attempting slower steps like reverting to an earlier System Restore point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: under some circumstances, this version of Windows seems to disable the wifi connection if it detects a physical connection. It turns out that one of the pseudo-interfaces installed by Wireshark looks like an active physical connection, so Windows was obediently shutting off the wifi.

Disabling the pseudo-interface let the wifi start properly.

Comment: I am on Windows 10 20.04 update. It's a clean install and there are not pseudo-interfaces. I am still having this issue.